# module code generation 'system' not supported

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

I'm new to typescript and angular 2.
I finished the course on pluralsight "Angular 2: Getting Started"
Now i want to be able to do what she did in visual studio.
I found this post made by her: 
http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/angular-2-getting-started-with-visual-studio-2015/

But when i do everything by the book i get the exception:
"Cannot resolve referenced file: $PathToProject$\tsconfig.json'." 
Where $PathToProject$ is the actual path towards the project.

After searching and searching... i came with the idea to maybe delete that file and just do it in the properties of my project. when I set "module system" to "system" I get the exception: "module code generation 'system' not supported."

I really tried everything and i'm running out of ideas.
Is it just me or is it really hard to get angular 2 to work in visual studio?

Anyways so the question basically is... how can i get deborah's example to work on vs2015.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i re-added the tsconfig.json file.

Kevin's answer in the following stackoverflow post fixed the first issue for me:

How to edit the Typescript 1.4 "specified task executable location"?

I'll post what he said here in case anything happens to it but please up-vote his post if it helped you!

Basically what Kevin said was go to the following places and rename (or if you have balls of steel you can delete) the "typescript" folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\

after that run a repair on your visual studio 2015 installation.